# Android - Smart password distribution

Tags: android, passwords

In my app there is an area that required password from the user.

In the first time that the user try to enter into this area he need to confirm some details in order to get a password that will let him insert into this area.
I'm trying to find good way to ditribut the passwords after the required details.
I have more then 5000 user so I don't want to send the password to each one by mail.

In addition, I want the password to be specific for each user so auto mail to each user is not a good solution.
I thought about GCM (Google cloud massaging) but I understand that this is not the right solution for my problem.

So my question is, what is the right way to ditribute passwords to users automatically and different password to each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some consultation I found the best way for my needs. I used Google Apps Script. This is a system that Google provide for every user to control smartly on his Google products like Gmail, Google docs and so on. You just go to script.google.com and you will see a start of script. In this page you can write a scripts using JavaScript to control your product. So I just wrote a script that check the mails in my Gmail and if this is an email with request from passwords and all the required details exists the script generate a password and reply automatically to the mail.
Here is part of the code:

```
function 
sendAutoPswrdEmails() 
{
 var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('passwords');
 var cmds;
 var stop = 0;

 cmds = label.getThreads(0, 10); //get first 10 mails
 for( var j = 10; cmds.length > 0; j+=10 ) 
 {
  for( var i = 0; i < cmds.length; ++i ) 
  {
    var email = cmds[i].getMessages()[0]; //email is a gmailMessage object
    if(email.isUnread())
    {
      var mailSubject = email.getSubject();
      var mailBody = email.getBody();
      //you may need to do extra parsing here, depending on your usage

      if(mailSubject == "whatever you want")
      {
        var mainTextExist = mailBody.indexOf("whatever you need");
        if(mainTextExist != -1)
        {
          var pswrd = someAlgorithm;
          email.reply("whatever you want to answer" + pswrd);
          cmds[i].markRead();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  cmds = [];
  cmds = label.getThreads(j, 10);//get next 10 mails
 }
}
```

The perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

## For generating random password, you can do this:

```
final TextView passwordText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordText); //The password
final EditText digitsField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.digitsField); //Length of password
Button generatePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generatePassword); //Generate Password

generatePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int passwordLength = Integer.parseInt(digitsField.getText().toString());
        String allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        char[] allowedCharsArray = allowedChars.toCharArray();
        char[] chars = new char[passwordLength];
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
            chars[i] = allowedCharsArray[random.nextInt(allowedChars.length())];
        }

        passwordText.setText(chars, 0, passwordLength);
    }
});
```

## For sending automatic email:

First of all, add these 3 libraries in your project: https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list

**Add this code to your activity:**

```
private void sendMail(String email, String subject, String messageBody) {
    Session session = createSessionObject();

    try {
        Message message = createMessage(email, subject, messageBody, session);
        new SendMailTask().execute(message);
    } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Message createMessage(String email, String subject, String messageBody, Session session) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Your GMail", "Username of your GMail"));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, email));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(messageBody);
    return message;
}

private Session createSessionObject() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    return Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("Your GMail", "Your password of GMail");
        }
    });
}

private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "Please wait", "Sending email...", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password Key has been sent. Please check your inbox.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Message... messages) {
        try {
            Transport.send(messages[0]);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Then to send an automatic email, call this on a button click or anything you want:**

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (networkInfo != null) {
    String email = user_email; // The email you will send to.
    String subject = "Password Key";
    String message = "Your password key is: " + password_key; //password_key is the password you will generate.
    sendMail(email, subject, message);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Network Error. Please connect to the internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the generation of the passwords is the easy part. The main question is how to distribut it in smart way?

Comment: Ok, I understand you. But why don't you want to send an auto-mail to each user? You can create a new specific email just for your app, if that's the problem. I use JMail  library in one of my apps to send emails automatically and it works perfectly. What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Automatic mail will have the same password for all users. How can you set automatic mail with different password for each user?

Comment: How will it be the same? In the code I wrote, it will generate random passwords. Or did I understand you incorrectly? How were you going to send that email? One email to many users at once? or a different automatic email to each user at different times according to the user's action?

Comment: Every user that will send me the required details will get automatic mail with password. Your code will generate different passwords but if I will create new mail (on gmail) for this task, the automatic mail will be the same for each user. I didn't find any way to send automatic mail with something different according to the mail content or something else in gmail. Or maybe you don't talk about gmail?

Comment: Ok, I think you misunderstood me. It will not be a static automatic email. You will include the random generated password in that email, so it will be different for all users. I have updated my answer as well to explain a little bit more. You will just have to replace some strings as I have specified, and don't worry nobody will know the password of your GMail. It will be secure when you build your app. Cheers. :)

Comment: Also make sure to add the internet permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @rafraph Did you try my solution?

Comment: Hussein, thank you very much on your big help. I started use it but there is still a problem. If I understand your solution, the mail will sent from my mail account from the user's phone. But in this way I didn't confirm that the mail from the user was really sent to me. As I explained, I require from the user to send me mail with some information in order to let him use some specific options. I don't want to give him the password before I confirm his mail really sent to me. But in your solution, when the user click on the butoon, automaticlly the mail with the password is sent to him.

Comment: Alright, no problem. You can still send the email when you confirm everything the user has sent to you. Just change the code a little bit and send the automatic email on confirmation of the information the user has entered.